# JMeter Array of variables to text file

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, beanshell

[image]I am running a query via JDBC request and I am able to get the data and place it in a variable array. The problem is I want the values of the variables to be saved to a text file. However, each variable is being given a unique number  appended to it i.e. SCORED_1, SCORED_2,SCORED_3 etc. I am using a beanshell post processor to write to the text file. The problem is I unless I define A LINE Number. How can I get all results from a SQL query and dump them into a single variable without the variables separated by brackets and line separated on their own row.

```
 import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

 // get variables from regular expression extractor 
 ClaimId = vars.get("SCORED _9"); // I want to just use the 
 SCORED variable to contain all values from the array 
 without "{[" characters.


  // pass true if want to append to existing file  
 // if want to overwrite, then don't pass the second 
 argument
 FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:/JMeter/apache- 
 jmeter-4.0/bin/FBCS_Verify_Final/Comp.txt", true);
 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
 out.write(ClaimId);
 out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
 out.close();
 fstream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

We are not telepathic enough to come up with the solution without seeing your query output and the result file format.

However I'm under impression that you're going into wrong direction. Given you're talking about `{[` characters it appears that you're using `Result Variable Name` field

[image]

which returns an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which should be treated differently

[image]

---

However if you switch to `Variable Names` field

[image]

JMeter will generate a separate variable per each result set row and it should be much easier to work with and eventually concatenate

[image]

More information:

- [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)
- [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks Dimitri. I attempted both methods Result variable and Variable Names. Variable name gives me the result I'm looking for but in an array and not as a single result like the Result variable. I am attempting to have each value of the array written to a text file. I am using a for loop in Beanshell Post processor but running into an eval error.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC request>Enter a Variable Name> Store as string>Add a Beanshell PostProcessor and add the following script.

```
    import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
{
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:/JMeter/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/FBCS_Verify_Final/Comp.txt", false);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);



 Count = vars.get("SCORED_#");
 Counter=Integer.parseInt(vars.get("SCORED_#"));
 for (int i=1;i<=Counter;i++)

 {

 ClaimId = vars.get("SCORED_"+i);
 out.write(ClaimId);
 out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

 }

 out.flush();
 out.close();
 fstream.close();

}
```